# My question is not answered there. How do I get rid of the blue banner?

Tags: support

Someone thought [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49972/can-i-dodge-if-i-dont-have-the-initiative?noredirect=1#comment101810_49972) could have an answer on [this another question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44433/how-to-divide-the-dice-pool-reactively).

It hasn't.

Actually, the latter question is about splitting dice and dodges in Vampire, while the one I asked is about something that Werewolf seems to do differently, or explain differently that all the other WoD games. I'm interested to know if Werewolf does something different than the other games, so, no, a question about how things in Vampire work doesn't answer my question.

Also, the accepted answer on the old question is mine. So, no, I didn't ask for something I had already answered on another question.

So, I would like to get rid of the blue banner saying my question may have an answer there. I have tried to edit the question, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What blue banner?

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton A blue textbox that says "This question may already have an answer here".

Comment: This is because one person has voted to close as duplicate. Therefore, as question-writer, you see the possible duplicate banner. I don't.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton . Ah, OK. I thought everyone was seeing this, and it could discourage answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the question such that it's more distinct such that the related question isn't obviously a duplicate, then wait for the close vote to expire.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if I can make them so distinct. In the very first paragraph I explain I am looking for something it appears different in W:tA than in all other games. The other question asks in the first sentence about V20.

Comment: So, the blue textbox appears only because someone voted to close the question, right?

Comment: Yep. *as a duplicate*. Close votes expire, and the question itself won't be modified with the notice until 5 close votes are acquired with a majority being for that close-as-duplicate.